# IE 11 multiple select not showing selected value when overflow

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

Good day,

I am having trouble with IE11 regarding multiple select.

When setting the selected option to an item that needs scrolling IE does not scroll to this item, but in Chrome it works fine.

Please [see](http://jsfiddle.net/8e31zo86/2/) my jsfiddle.

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
    select {
        max-height:60px;
        width:100px;
        float:left;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select multiple="multiple" id="selectBox">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option value="3">1</option>
    <option value="4">1</option>
    <option value="5">1</option>
    <option value="6">1</option>
    <option value="7">1</option>
    <option value="8">1</option>
    <option value="9">1</option>
    <option value="10">1</option>
    <option value="11">1</option>
    <option value="12">1</option>
    <option value="13">1</option>
    <option value="14">1</option>
    <option value="15">1</option>
    <option value="16">1</option>
    <option value="17">1</option>
    <option value="18">1</option>
    <option value="19">1</option>
    <option value="20">1</option>
    <option value="21">1</option>
    <option value="22" selected="selected">4</option>
 </select>
</body>
```

Is this a known issue? Or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**
Please see updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e31zo86/12/) with workaround/fix

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm this, but don't know why it behaves like that. Setting the attribute with javascript does seem to work tough. Perhaps that can be an alternative.

Comment: Okay I have updated my jsfiddle to prove that the javascript route works. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/8e31zo86/3/

Comment: I have added a new jsfiddle to show you my issue, I am using angularjs and I am getting the same result, please [see](http://jsfiddle.net/e4mn79zt/) my new fiddle.

Comment: This is most likely as intended. With it being a multi-select, it's possible to have both the first and last items selected... Where should it scroll to in that scenario??

Comment: In my case I limit the user to one selection, so there **WILL** always only be one selected value.

Comment: @wf4 In my opinion it should scroll to the first selected item. Setting the attribute via javascript works as expected, but the question is, why wouldn't IE do it automatically?

Comment: That's correct, plain javascript works fine but angularjs does not.  And why does IE11 not do this by default, can we somehow test in another IE version?

Comment: You can try pressing F12 in IE and in the topright corner of the popin, swith Edge to another version.

Comment: Thanks, but I tested on browserstack and it looks like it's an issue on all the latest IE versions(IE8+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, please see my workaround/fix below:

```
(function (e) {                                   
 if (e.find(':selected').val()) {
     var currentVal = e.find(':selected').val();
     console.log(currentVal);
     e.val('');
     e.val(currentVal);
  }
})($('#selectBox'));
```

In my case a had to wrap this function in a `setTimeout`

Comment: [upvoted] came across here looking for a solution for when replacing options (up/down) in the multiple select and the selected options goes below the fold, it's not visible in IE11. it kinda works with this solution but still isn't perfect as it moves the list to have the selected item on top.